# Laravel Project on local Xampp mysql error : file_put_contents: Failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: laravel, session, xampp, localhost, storage

I have developed a laravel project on one laptop using local xampp mysql and want to install it on another laptop. I am having this error: file_put_contents(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sfms/storage/framework/sessions/VS0cObLn8ItoKMt5HQJOlZ0srelpMLsSwm5ZQcPa): Failed to open stream: Permission:
I have tried the following but they did not work:

1. php artisan cache:clear
2. php artisan config:clear
3. manually deleted vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ConfigClearCommand.php
   among others.
   Please, I need your assistance. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can run this command

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data ./storage ./bootstrap
```

And then use the command

```
sudo chmod -R 755 ./storage ./bootstrap
```

Comment: Thanks. I am still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Run this two command for permission.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 ./storage
sudo chmod -R 777 ./bootstrap
```

Answer (score 0):

I run the following code in the terminal and it worked for me:

chmod -R 777 storage